# How to prevent scroll on cell focus when using cellNav?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I have a grid that requires `ui.grid.cellNav`, however the first time I click on any cell that allows focus (`allowCellFocus` -> default is `true`) an scroll event happens moving up the clicked cell out of the viewport, my grid has many rows so the user needs to scroll up to reveal the clicked cell again. It only happens the first time a cell is clicked.

I've found in ui-grid.js the code below trigering the behavior:

```
if (grid.cellNav.lastRowCol === null || grid.cellNav.lastRowCol.row !== newRowCol.row || grid.cellNav.lastRowCol.col !== newRowCol.col){
                    grid.api.cellNav.raise.navigate(newRowCol, grid.cellNav.lastRowCol);
                    grid.cellNav.lastRowCol = newRowCol;
                  }
```

Steps to replicate:

1. Go to http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/202_cellnav
2. Scroll down to reveal the sample grid of the page (it doesn't happen with age since it has allowCellFocus to false.
3. Click on any cell of ID, Name or Address
4. A scroll will happen if you haven't already scrolled to the bottom of the page

Clicking again in any other cell doesn't trigger scroll behavior a second time. To replicate the behavior you need to reload the page.

Can I prevent this behavior, while still using cellNav?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What browser are you experiencing this?  I can't duplicate on the doc example using latest Chrome.

Comment: Thanks for checking, I'm also using an updated Chrome, the issue doesn't happen in Firefox actually.

Comment: I checked in chrome again, if i scroll all the way down in the page revealing the sample grid completely and then click on any cell scroll event won't happen. It happens if the grid is partially visible in the view port, then scroll event is noticeable. Again only on page load, second time click on any cell is fine.